# How can a discord bot use one of the functions that are in the same code?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I copied the discord tutorial code from
[freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-discord-bot-with-python/) and I am making a discord.py bot that receives a link, but then replaces one of the words from the link. The code to replace one of the words is:

```
def b_link():
    user_input=input("Enter a website")
    link=user_input.replace("com","ca") 
    return (link)
```

This code is a part of the code that activates the discord bot, but whenever i type the link into discord for the bot to replace a word, the bot does not reply to it but I get the input command on my python shell and I have to type the link in the shell instead of on discord for the bot to reply.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? How do I get to code so that I can type the link into discord and the bot picks it up from there only.

My entire code is as follows:

```
``import discord
import os
client = discord.Client()
Token="<redacted>"

def b_link():
  user_input=input("Enter a website")
  link=user_input.replace("com","ca")
  return (link)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in successfully {0.user}'.format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!br https'):
      link=br_link()
      await message.channel.send(link)
client.run(Token)
```

Comment: **Please reset your discord token immediately; by posting it here anyone may now use it to take over your discord bot. I have redacted it as a temporary stopgap, but anyone may still view it in the edit history.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input()` function will work on the "backend" of things, so it will not directly work with your Discord channel messages. I recommend first changing your function `b_link` to something like:

```
def b_link(original):
    link = original.replace("com", "ca") 
    return (link)
```

where it takes in a parameter instead of using `input`. Then, in your `on_message` function, you can instead do something like:

```
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
       return

   if message.content.startswith('!br https'):
       original_link = str(message.content) 
       original_link = original_link.split(" ")[1]
       link = br_link(original_link)

       await message.channel.send(link)
```

Using `message.content` gets the full message string, and we can get the original link by using the `str.split` method. Then, we passed the original link to the `b_link` function, and sends the new link on the Discord channel.

While this will work, stylistically, it is better to put helper functions in a separate Python script and import them in. Additionally, you should look into using [bot commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) instead of client events for more convenience.